# Why the elements disappear after I use push_back() function of vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to use `std::vector` in a class to realize a muti-way tree.

Each time when I want to add a child in on of the member, I use a function `addMember`. I'm using VS2017 to debug this program. In this function scope the parent's children vector has actually add the elements by `push_back()`, but after exiting the function, the address of vector will change and the elements I have added will disappear.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class member {
public:
    string name;
    member* parent;
    vector<member*> children;
    member(string m_name,member* m_parent):name(m_name),parent(m_parent){}
};

class familyTree {
private:
    member ancestor;
public:
    member* getAncestor() { return &ancestor; }
    familyTree(member& m_ancestor):ancestor(m_ancestor){}
    member* searchMember(string name,member* node,bool& flag);
    void addMember(string name, int children_number,vector<string>& children_name);
};

member* familyTree::searchMember(string name, member* node,bool& flag) {
    member* find = NULL;
    if (node) {
        if (node->name == name)
            find = node;
        else {
            if (!flag) {
                for (auto iter = node->children.begin(); iter != node->children.end(); iter++) {
                    find = searchMember(name, *iter, flag);
                    if (flag)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return find;
}

void familyTree::addMember(string name,int children_number,vector<string>& children_name) {
    bool flag = false;
    member* parent = searchMember(name, getAncestor(), flag);
    for (auto i : children_name) {
        member* child = new member(i,parent);
        parent->children.push_back(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have no method called `addChild()`. Did you mean `addMember()`? Please write a consistent question for people to understand. Also, I presume you're really going to delete that `new member` somewhere? And what do you mean that _"the address of vector will change and the elements I have add will disappear"_? Could you show examples of testing this, and the output you get, versus what you expected?

Comment: Thx,I've corrected that.I never delete by any function I wrote.In single-step debug model,I am sure the new members have been added to the vector,but once I exit the addMember function,the address of the vector I just operated will change,and the elements in it will be cleared off.

Comment: Damn，I found that it went well in exe, the elements won't disappear,but it would do that if I used single-step debug model.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there is something wrong with the `familyTree::searchMember` function. Here was what you posted:

```
member* familyTree::searchMember(string name, member* node, bool& flag) {
    member* find = NULL;
    if (node) {
        if (node->name == name)
            find = node;
        else {
            if (!flag) {
                for (auto iter = node->children.begin(); iter != node->children.end(); iter++) {
                    find = searchMember(name, *iter, flag);
                    if (flag)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return find;
}
```

Notice that there was no method to set the `flag = true` once you have found the correct node.

**The 2nd `if` statement should be:**

```
if (node->name == name) {
    find = node;
    flag = true;
}
```

Otherwise within your `for` loop,

```
for (auto iter = node->children.begin(); iter != node->children.end(); iter++) {
    find = searchMember(name, *iter, flag);
    if (flag)
        break;
}
```

even if there was a successful search, the `for` loop does not `break` and so it continues on, and the next child you search is guaranteed to not be a match.

Note that the way your `searchMember` function is structured results in `NULL` being returned if you search through a node **that does not have a matching name** and **does not have any children** because the `for` loop is skipped (no children to iterate through). So you end up with a lot of `NULL` pointers being assigned to `parent` in `addMember`.

Comment: Thx so much,it's a bad mistake. I am so careless.It's a pity that this is not the place where going wrong.I found my problem just when I wanted to add elements to the root node,so the search function return the correct address.I am still confused about my problem.Thank you all the same1